# Cannot create Release Pipeline in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-task

I am trying to create a Release Pipeline to release my SQL Database Project in Azure DevOps Project

I have created a Build pipeline fine, but when I go to releases and click on the `New pipeline` nothing happens.

[image]

Tried this with multiple accounts, different browsers and no luck.

checked the browser console for errors and it is clear there as well.

Any ideas?

Comment: refresh the page your are on & try clicking again on the same link.

Comment: Inspect using `F12` in your browser to find any error you are getting

Comment: @AnkushJain Refreshing doesn't help. also the browser console is clear... no errors

Comment: Also tried Edge and FF, same issue!

Comment: This started working now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the same issue. I was able to work around it with steps described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops-project/azure-devops-project-github).

Create a fake release from any GitHub project. You will see brand new release pipeline after that: 
[image: New release pipeline]

Next pipeline creation works well. I hope it will help you. I am sorry, that this is not working out of the box, but you can make it work with this steps :)

Comment: Thanks. that works. its unfortunate that such a basic happy path scenario is broken! :(

Comment: Word on the street is that they already fix this. I didn't check.